# Вычисление чистой прибыли с помощью цикла

Tags: python

**Задача:**

Написать функцию `calculate_profit`, принимающую три параметра:

- `amount` – начальная сумма, которую мы кладем на депозит;
- `percent` – ​​годовая процентная ставка;
- `period` – количество лет (время, на которое деньги кладутся на депозит).

Функция должна рассчитать и вернуть сумму чистой прибыли за все время.

Если переданные в функцию amount, percent или period равны 0, функция должна возвращать 0

**Проблема:** мой код работает только на 1 год, на период с большим количеством лет считает неверно

```
from typing import Union

def calculate_profit(amount: int, percent: Union[float, int], period: int) -> Union[float, int]:
    if amount == 0:
        return 0
    if percent == 0:
        return 0
    if period == 0:
        return 0

    Amount = amount  
    years =  0
    while period > years: 
        Amount = amount * percent / 100
        years += 1
        return Amount * period
```

Comment: а новая переменная Amount с похожим до степени смешения именем введена специально, чтобы запутывать?

Answer (score 2):

Если вам нужна не **чистая прибыль**, а **итоговое кол-во денег после заданного периода**, то уберите *уменьшаемое* из оператора `return`.

```
return amount * (1+percent/100)**period` # без цикла
return amount # любой из циклов
```

---

1. Вообще решается без цикла:

```
def calculate_profit(amount: int, percent: Union[float, int], period: int) ->Union[float, int]:
    if 0 in (amount, percent, period):
        return 0
    return amount - amount * (1+percent/100)**period
```

2. Цикл `for`:

```
def calculate_profit(amount: int, percent: Union[float, int], period: int) ->Union[float, int]:
    if 0 in (amount, percent, period):
        return 0
    start = amount
    for _ in range(period):
        amount *= (1 + percent / 100)
    return start-amount
```

3. Цикл `while`:

```
def calculate_profit(amount: int, percent: Union[float, int], period: int) ->Union[float, int]:
    if 0 in (amount, percent, period):
        return 0
    start = amount
    year = 0
    while year<period:
        amount *= (1 + percent / 100)
        year += 1
    return start-amount
```

---

Да, собственно, и проверка на ноль тоже не нужна:

1. Если `amount==0`, то мы умножаем `0` на число и получаем `0`.
2. Если `percent==0`, то мы умножаем на `1` и получаем `amount`.
3. Если `period==0`, то мы:

   1. В циклах ничего не сделаем, потому что цикл и не запустится.
   2. В функции без цикла умножим на `1`, потому что `a**0==1`.

Однако в случае с нулем в переменных `amount` и `percent` в функциях с циклом от проверки есть толк, поскольку мы завершаем работу без *умножений `0`* и *умножения на `1`*, соответсвенно.
Тогда функции будет выглядеть так:

1. Без цикла

```
def calculate_profit(amount: int, percent: Union[float, int], period: int) ->Union[float, int]:
    return amount - amount * (1+percent/100)**period
```

2. Цикл `for`:

```
def calculate_profit(amount: int, percent: Union[float, int], period: int) ->Union[float, int]:
    if 0 in (amount, percent):
        return 0
    start = amount
    for _ in range(period):
        amount *= (1 + percent / 100)
    return start-amount
```

3. Цикл `while`:

```
def calculate_profit(amount: int, percent: Union[float, int], period: int) ->Union[float, int]:
    if 0 in (amount, percent):
        return 0
    start = amount
    year = 0
    while year<period:
        amount *= (1 + percent / 100)
        year += 1
    return start-amount
```

Comment: но не нужна чистая прибыль за любой период

Answer (score 1):

Ниже рабочий код с добавленной проверкой.

1. Исправил формулу возврата.
2. Сдвинул return правильно.
3. Не надо использовать переменные, отличающиеся лишь типом буквы (строчная/прописная) - плохой стиль, путаются потом.

```
from typing import Union

def calculate_profit(amount: int, percent: Union[float, int], period: int) ->Union[float, int]:
    if amount == 0:
        return 0
    if percent == 0:
        return 0
    if period == 0:
        return 0

    Initial_value = amount
    years =  0
    while period > years:
        amount = amount * (1 + percent / 100)
        years += 1
    return amount - Initial_value

print(calculate_profit (1000, 10, 2)) # 210.0 на печати
```

Comment: Если ответ был полезным, его можно отметить плюсом (нажать треугольник вверх слева от вопроса). Если ответ решил поставленный вопрос - принять ответ (нажать на галку под треугольниками слева).  Можно и то, и другое, если ещё и  понравилось:-)

Answer (score 1):

Работает только для одного года у вас потому что в цикле есть строчка

```
return Amount * period
```

Как только выполнение до нее доходит, то сразу же происходит выход из функции возвращается текущий результат. Это именно то, что делает `return` - прекращает выполнение функции.

Answer (score -1):

```
def calculate_profit(amount: int, percent: Union[float, int], period: int) ->Union[float, int]:
    for year in range(period):
            profit *= 1 + percent / 100
        return profit - amount
```

Comment: Оно не будет работать. Вы бы хоть проверили. И, как понимаю, ответ @n1tr0xs вас не впечатлил, даже плюса он от вас не получил.